# Locating pairs of elements from two arrays that are within a fixed range from each other

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm

I have two arrays of sorted elements that are not necessarily equal in size (but are equal in dimension). Currently I am using a nested loop through each possible pair and checking if the absolute difference of the two is in the correct range. Is there a way to do this more efficiently? This is the largest contribution to runtime for this program.

```
timeList = []
for i in range(len(data1)):
        time1 = data1.iloc[i, 2] #Time is in column 2
        for j in range(len(data2)):
            time2 = data2.iloc[j, 2]
            # 100 ns
            if abs(time1 - time2) <= 100000:
                timeList.append(abs(time1-time2))
```

Comment: By what are the dataframes sorted? By the time?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, by time

Comment: You can use the two pointers approach to maintain the index of the first element in the second array that falls in the desired range while iterating over the first array, and break from the inner loop when the element of the second array goes outside the range. If you don't need to collect the list of absolute differences but instead want to calculate some metric based on it, complexity can probably be improved from `O(cnt_pairs + len(data1) + len(data2))` to `O(len(data1) + len(data2))` using the same approach.